# Communicate to main class using Mqtt subscriber

Tags: java, multithreading, network-programming, mqtt

I have a main class that spins up a mqtt subscriber in another thread(basically a service that listens for a message to arrive).  When that subscriber receives that message, I need it to forward to my main class so it can do a computation on that message.

In the subscriber, I have a messageArrived function.  I'm not certain on the way of going about communicating that message to my main class.  I'm thinking maybe some kind of networking like sending a socket from the subscriber to the main class that listens.  But would like to consider other advice.  All of this is done on the same machine.

Snippet from Subscriber that gets spun up in another thread from main class:

```
@Override
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws MqttException{
//send message to main class somehow...
}
```

Main class that needs message from code above:

```
new Thread(optSubscriber).start();  //spin up subscriber service to listen for messages aka messageArrived

//somehow grab that message from messageArrived and place into next function
computeMessageFromSubscriber(message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push the message object to a collection (e.g. Vector) and then poll that collection from the processing thread.

Also rather than do the work on a predetermined single thread, why not look at the java.util thread pool models, which encapsulated this pattern in a way that scales

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Comment: After doing some more research on multithreading, this is a really good alternative to what I initially planned.